# $m^*(E)=\infty$ in Caratheodory's criterion for Lebesgue measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble with the $m^*(E)=\infty$ case from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064678/proving-the-carathedory-criterion-for-lebesgue-measurability). I've looked at the answers where $E$ is split into countably infinitely many bounded subsets, but I still cannot prove this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covering $\mathbb R$ with countably many boxes $B_n$ we see that for every elementary set $A$,
\begin{align}m^*(A\setminus (B_n\cap E))+m^*(A\cap(B_n\cap E))&\ge m^*(A)\tag{subadditivity}\\
&=m(A)\end{align}
and
\begin{align}m^*(A\setminus(B_n\cap E))+m^*(A\cap(B_n\cap E))
&=m^*(((A\cap B_n)\setminus E)\cup(A\setminus B_n))+m^*((A\cap B_n)\cap E))\\
&\le m^*((A\cap B_n)\setminus E)+m^*(A\setminus B_n)+m^*((A\cap B_n)\cap E))\tag{subadditivity}\\
&=m(A\cap B_n)+m(A\setminus B_n)\tag{$A\cap B_n$ and $A\setminus B_n$ are elementary}\\
&=m(A),\tag{additivity}
\end{align}
so $m^*(A\setminus (B_n\cap E))+m^*(A\cap(B_n\cap E))=m(A)$. By the finite case and the fact that countable unions of Lebesgue measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable, we conclude that $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(B_n\cap E)$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Does anyone know why I see a giant blank space to the left of my 2nd `align` environment?